# Basis of Symmetric Polynomials on Variables with Conditions

Tags: symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions

It is well know that there are many bases for the ring of symmetric polynomials on $k$ variable. For example, if we define $p_n = \sum_{i=1}^k x_i^n$, then every symmetric polynomial can be written as a finite sum of finite products of the $p_n$.

My question is: if we want to impose some polynomial conditions on the variables $x_1,\dots,x_k$, how does this change the basis of symmetric functions?

For example, if we take $k=2$ and impose the relation $x_1x_2=1$, then we see that every symmetric polynomials can be written as a finite sum of $p_n$ (without products necessary). That is, if $f$ is a symmetric polynomials then
$$f(x_1,x_2) = \sum_{1\leq i\leq j\leq N} a_{i,j}\left(x_1^ix_2^j + x_1^jx_2^i\right) = \sum_{1\leq i \leq j \leq N} a_{i,j} \left( x_1^{j-i} + x_2^{j-i} \right)= \sum_{1\leq i \leq j \leq N} a_{i,j} p_{j-i}(x_1,x_2)$$

Is there a general theory that tackles these questions?

Edit: I am interested in the smallest possible (whatever smallest may mean) set of polynomials that would additively generate the symmetric polynomials under a condition. For example, with no condition we would need $\prod_j p_j^{n_j}$ for all choices of $n_j\geq0$, whereas with the example condition given we only need $p_n$ for all choices of $n>0$.

Comment: In your particular example, the condition you're imposing is itself symmetric in the variables.  Is that what you want always?  If so, the question is answerable via the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials (that the elementary symmetric polynomials form a free generating set as an algebra).

Comment: @JBL, I don't necessarily want the condition to be symmetric. This was just the simplest example for which I have an answer to my question. But I don't think the fundamental theorem would necessarily answer my question even if the condition were symmetric. That is, I am interested in the smallest set of polynomials that generate the space under the condition (for whatever is the best definition of smallest). I will update the question to better reflect this.

Comment: I don't have any insight into what happens with non-symmetric conditions.  With symmetric conditions, the symmetric polynomials in $n$ variables $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ are $\mathbb{F}[e_1, \ldots, e_n]$, where the $e_i$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials, so in that case you are "just" asking about the structure of the quotient ring $\mathbb{F}[e_1, \ldots, e_n] / (\text{your relations})$.

Comment: Yes, in the symmetric case I am asking about the structure of $\mathbb{F}[e_1,\dots,e_n]/(\mbox{my relations})$. So, my question still remains: is anything known about a (minimal) generating set?

Comment: In that case you're asking for the Hilbert series of an arbitrary quotient of a polynomial ring over a field.  I am not a commutative algebraist, but many things are known about this; for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_series_and_Hilbert_polynomial#Computation_of_Hilbert_series_and_Hilbert_polynomial is certainly relevant.  I would look for any textbook on commutative algebra to learn more.